# jQuery copy HTML elment and add value to all children IDs

Tags: jquery, variables, append, clone, attr

interesting one. i'm working on a big, modular form that the user can add or remove services in and need to reach into the DOM, copy an HTML element, and add a value to the end of both it and it's children's ID's.

So for example:

```
<li id="serviceModule" class="serviceModule">
    <ol>
        <li id="subModuleTypeA">subModule</li>
        <li id="subModuleTypeB">
            <ol>
                <li id="subModuleTypeASubModuleX">subSubModule</li>
                <li id="subModuleTypeASubModuleY">subSubModule</li>
                <li id="subModuleTypeASubModuleZ">subSubModule</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li id="subModuleTypeC">subModule</li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

Would become:

```
<li id="serviceModule1" class="serviceModule">
    <ol>
        <li id="subModuleTypeA1">subModule</li>
        <li id="subModuleTypeB1">
            <ol>
                <li id="subModuleTypeASubModuleX1">subSubModule</li>
                <li id="subModuleTypeASubModuleY1">subSubModule</li>
                <li id="subModuleTypeASubModuleZ1">subSubModule</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li id="subModuleTypeC1">subModule</li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

Method that adds value:

```
$.fn.valulator = function(magic){

    var thiis = $(this),
        el,
        id;

    thiis.add(thiis.children()).each(function(){

        el = $(this);
        id = el.attr('id');

        el.attr('id', id + magic);
    });

    return this;
};
```

Binding that triggers `valulator`:

```
$add.click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $index = $index + 1;
    $('.serviceModule')
        .clone()
        .valulator($index)
        .appendTo('#services');
});
```

Thanks for your help! Here's a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/phqvr/3/

---

UPDATE

Finding that the first issue i'm running into within `valulator()` is that `children()` only brings up direct descendants.. instead i need to search ALL elements.

Comment: `el[id]` is always undefined, so it never enters the `if (el[id]){` statement, and doesn't increment your id's. Out of interest, what console errors are you getting, as I get none on your fiddle.

Comment: @Jeemusu actually, not getting any. forgot to update the post- it was just a syntax error. why is el[id] always undefined? i understand the syntax to search elements that match the attribute[http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/]. going to update the post with more findings

Comment: The problem is your .each() loop, it's not looping though the children.

Comment: @Jeemusu just what I discovered. can you recommend a way to traverse thiis and all of its children? i.e. something like thiis.add(thiis.filter(' > *'))

Comment: @Jeemusu ahhh... thiis.find('*').andSelf()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it; there were two issues.

1) as mentioned in the update, `children()` only traversed one level down- reworked it to:

```
thiis.find('*').andSelf().each()
```

2) in my Fiddle, there was an added conditional `if(el[id])` that would always fail. replaced with below code to prevent additions to elements that didn't have ID's to begin with:

```
if (id){}
```

Full working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/phqvr/4/

```
    $.fn.valulator = function(magic){

        var thiis = $(this),
            el,
            id;

        thiis.find('*').andSelf().each(function(){

            el = $(this);
            id = el.attr('id');            

            if (id){

                el.attr('id', id + magic);
            }
        });

        return this;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code,

`$(this).find('li').attr('id',$(this).find('li').attr('id')+ magic);`

I have changed fiddle, check this http://jsfiddle.net/B2SdM/

It will generate new element with id 1,2,3... etc.

Comment: Thank you, but replaces all IDs with the same value, obv not very functional. see my working answer

Comment: It will not replace all id, but only for new module that is created by clicking add button.